# After Installing ADT Plugin, Welcome to Android Development Doesnt Appear

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I am stuck after installation Eclipse with ADT Plugin. After all the steps are completed, it should show "Welcome to android Development" but instead I just see Java development.

My setup is as follows:

Java JDK 6
Eclipse Juno SR1
Android SDK 4.1- All default packages and USB driver
ADT Plugin

After ADT installation, Eclipse restarts and it should then show "Welcome to Android Development but it doesn't

Anyone knows what could be the issue? appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Check if you could create a "new Android Application Project". If you can, there's no issue at all.

Comment: @zander I did check that. When I go to New-There is a dropdown list of Projects to select but there is no android application project in the list.

Comment: @zander, Actually under New- When I select Project- It now shows a bunch of options which also has new android Application project. It does lemme create one. Does that means, it's setup properly?

Comment: Yes! Don't stick on to the welcome screen Mr. Developer :) Good luck

Comment: Thanks @zander. I am a newbie :-) Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this
`Window > Customize Perspective > Menu Visibility > Expand 'File' > Expand 'New' > Tick 'Android Project'`
and Then, look for new `Android application project`

Comment: Does anyone know why this is happening and does Google know about it?  They could at least update their install procedure but more importantly it makes you wonder what else may not be getting set up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem on eclipse juno.

No "Welcome page" appeared, I could not create a project, compilation didn't work and "Graphical layout" didn't work.

It have been fixed by: Window > preferences > general > startup and shutdown: check "Android development toolkit"

Reestart eclipse.

Of course you have to be configured this: Window - Preferences - Android - SDK Location and setup SDK path.

Comment: Geez, this had me stumped for a whole day.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found a real nice solution [here](http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/04/how-to-setup-android-application.html)

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem. I am running "Eclipse for Mobile Developers", Version: Juno Service Release 1, Build id: 20120920-0800 on Windows XP SP3

The reason I am concerned is that i needed to hook up a new Android SDK to my newly downloaded Eclipse IDE. The "I[nstalling the Eclipse Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)" instructions, under the "Configure the ADT Plugin" heading, said, "... you must specify the location of your Android SDK directory..." and to do that

1. In the "Welcome to Android Development" window that appears, select Use existing
2. Browse and select the location of the Android SDK directory you recently downloaded and unpacked.

I solved my hook-up problem by clicking window->preferences->Android & change sdk location:

- from: C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk    [it apparently sensed an old installation]
- to: C:\Documents and Settings\joe\Local Settings\Application Data\Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but the Android SDK Manager icon was missing from the ADT Eclipse bundle. The following steps now shows the Android SDK Manager icon and the option from the "Window" bar.

This is for a MAC but I think it should apply to a Windows install as well.

Click on:

Window -> Customize Perspective -> Command Groups Availability

Check "Android SDK and AVD Manager" and that's it

Thanks to zander's suggestion, I poked around some more and figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Linux I encounter this problem and it was because had a previous installation of the ADT. Remove the files `rm ~/.android -rf` and restart eclipse.