# SDK Manager does not pop up when clicked

Tags: android

I am having a problem with my SDK Manager. It doesn't pop up when I click the icon of the window.

I have downloaded the file for the 2nd time but it still doesn't pop up, I followed the  instructions in here [After Installing ADT Plugin, Welcome to Android Development Doesnt Appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756839/after-installing-adt-plugin-welcome-to-android-development-doesnt-appear) as well i must have missed something but all is well I'm just missing google com.google.android.gms. And for that I cant continue with my project.

How can I fix this mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are missing `com.google.android.gms.*`, it means you need to import `google-play-services_lib` after opening it as project. Actually you should read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13734564/1306419) and follow it. Hope this helps you solve the error. If not then please comment.